# what is the difference between present simple and present progressive in this example?

Tags: meaning-in-context, present-continuous, present-simple

If I want to know if someone is being harassed by someone else, should I ask:

"does he harass you?"

or

"is he harassing you?"

I think they mean the same thing, but "does he harass you" puts the focus on the fact and "is he harassing you" puts the focus on frequency, but I am wondering if "is he harassing you" means I suspect the person is being harassed, whereas if I ask "does he harass you" I have no suspicion and the question sounds more neutral?

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is wrong:

**Does he harass you?** asks whether he is in the habit of harassing you.

**Is he harassing you?** asks whether his current behaviour amounts to harassment.

It's like asking:

> Do you swim?

which means do you enjoy swimming / do you go swimming, and:

> Are you swimming

which asks whether you are swimming now or possibly later today.

Comment: "current" can also mean "belonging to the present time" like this month or this year, not just happening at this moment. –

Answer (score 1):

For a verb like "harass",  the continuous form "be harassing" indicates a current but temporary condition.  It refers to an act that is currently happening.

The simple present tense refers to a general fact. Something that might not be happening right now but does happen often.

So if you see a man who is making his female employee feel uncomfortable you could say "Is he harassing you?". But later you could ask "Does he harass you (everyday)?"

Comment: I meant "is he harassing you" in the sense of "has he been harassing you recently", so not necessarily at this moment, but recently. – anouk 1 min ago   Edit

Comment: "Is he harassing you" means "at the moment" If you want to talk about a past you could use "was he harassing you"

Comment: "current" can also mean "belonging to the present time" like this month or this year, not just happening at this moment.